# Infusion Altar Symmetry question

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

Do non-symmetry related items count towards calculations against the symmetry if they are located within the max range to check for symmetry related items?

[This](http://ftbwiki.org/Tutorial:Infusion_(Thaumcraft_4)) tutorial is extremely detailed but fails to mention specifically if items that do not count TOWARD symmetry in-fact throw OFF symmetry or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this for my response and have found that non related items do throw off symmetry if they are in the max range. I did this in a superflat world to make sure there was nothing throwing off the results. unfortunately i can provide screenshots or anything as i am on holiday atm and don't have access to my home computer.

Hope this helps though

Comment: so to otherwise confirm, in order to run a Infusion Altar at maximum efficiency I really need to clear an area that freaking large!?

Comment: Yes - it sucks and you never know it might get changed in the future but at the moment yes. If you have buildcraft i would recommend using a filler to clear the space it will be much easier